# How to replace layouts In a scrollview dynamically when a button is pressed

Tags: android, scrollview

Actually I'm trying to replace the layout inside a scrollview when a button is pressed, like a fragment. but I don't want to use the fragments I made a xml layout file which must be inflated in a scrollview when I click the button which is already in the layout already present in scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question exactly, but as i understood you want to show a layout inside a scroll view when a button click, that easy you can create a layout inside it and set visibility to invisible then when the button click make the layout visible, explain more certificate about your question then i can answer better.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use viewFlipper

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="First Child"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Second Child"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Third Child"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

and in java you can change between viewFlipper views like this

```
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
```